# Implementing Loading Phase of Angular 2 App

Tags: angular

My Angular 2 app performs some initialization at the beginning such as retrieve a session id. During this phase, I want the app to display a component or modal which indicates that the app is loading (at the same time disabling regular functionality). Once the initialization has finished the app should navigate to the URL the user originally selected.

How would you implement this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide your code. People here would not be able to help you if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you want to achieve.

Create a component, called for example "initializationComponent" that is shown as when your url is "path/myInitialization". In this component prepare an HTML in order to comunicate that the app is loading.

Inside ngOnInit() method call function for retrieve your session id. When this method finished just move to another component executing navigateByUrl

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How can I determine the url that was originally called by the user?

Comment: you mean "window.location.host" ?

Comment: The user will pick an entry URL when he first calls the app (any possible route). I want to save that route and then navigate to it once the app has fully loaded.

Comment: Ok you can save it in LocalStorage or store it in a static variable inside AppComponent and then when your initialization finished get it.